# How to add href{} to caption in figure environment

Tags: hyperref, url, href

Can anyone tell me how to add `href{}` to `\caption{}` in figure environment? I keep getting TEX capacity exceeded error. My link in `href{}` contains underscore characters, escaping them doesn't help..

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you're trying achieve with `\href`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you want something like this--

[image: Caption-href]

Well, that can be achieved with this--

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=15em]{example-image-golden}
    \caption{More about the \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio}
             {golden ration}}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Your questions are welcome in TeX.SE... if possible with a Minimum Working Example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3350/146828)) to show what you tried.  That will help contributors to better understand what you need, and not duplicate valuable work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when I run your code it works, but when I put in there my url, that is https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Codifying-the-neighbourhood-structure-Arie-P./e9b3f350363570cbff3da4678a2fe72f92c283aa/figure/10, it doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't face any problem doing that too. I just changed the hyperlink and you can click [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Va3DZTOoL4q1hQa3757tGdZekx_kdJmy/view?usp=sharing) to see if it works for you.  Maybe your LaTeX compiler parses hyperlinks somewhat differently. Have you tried doing it in Overleaf ?